# How many solutions exist in reals

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Let $f(x)= x^3+3x^2+6x+2009$ and 
$$g(x)=\dfrac{1}{x-f(1)}+\dfrac{2}{x-f(2)}+\dfrac{3}{(x-f(3)}.$$ The number of real solutions of $g(x)=0$ is

Comment: Surely you can use latex considering you have been using this site for a while?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $$g(x)=\frac{\alpha}{x-a}+\frac{\beta}{x-b}+\frac{\gamma}{x-c}$$ Reduce to same denominator, expand and simplify to get $$g(x)=\frac{(a b \gamma +a \beta  c+\alpha  b c)-x (a \beta +a \gamma +b \alpha  +b \gamma
   + c \alpha +c \beta)+x^2 (\alpha +\beta +\gamma )}{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)}$$

I am sure that you can take from here.